# Setting multi node on Elasticsearch 2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I started to use Elasticsearch 2.0. When I want to use multiple node on one cluster, it seems it's not not working.

I tried two different methods to create multi node.

First, I used my localhost and created two instances of Elasticsearch.

Second, I used two different computers (one instance on my local computer and one instance in server and I used `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` to bind them) for this multi node.

It's different from Elasticsearch 1.x version. And I read that multicast has already removed. So how to setting the config file for multi node on a cluster in Elasticsearch 2.0??

Here is my config setting for different server

```
cluster.name: "cluster_node_1"
node.name: "test1_node1_ES2"
http.cors.enabled: true
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.cors.enable: true
network.bind_host: 10.21.126.151
network.publish_host: 10.21.126.151
network.host: 10.21.126.151
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.21.126.151", "10.21.126.145"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the config on your first node (i.e. localhost)? Do you get any errors? if yes, which ones and on which hosts?

Comment: Hi Val, there no error on the config. my config is same on localhost and on other server. the difference is just the ip address. when I ran each instance on my localhost and server its can run normally. but can't bind together on one cluster. I supposed it should shown 2 nodes on web page.

Comment: You mention that you used your local computer and another computer as your two nodes, what do the unicast hosts represent, is one of those your local computer?

Comment: yes one of the computer is local computer. 10.21.126.151 is my local IP and 10.21.126.145 is the other computer's IP. I tried using two instance of elasticsearch on my local computer but it's not working. this method is working with elasticsearch 1.x version. Maybe there is something wrong with config file?? Thanks

Comment: Anyone can help me with this issue? Maybe can tell me how to setting the config file for use two nodes? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. 
I need to add ports in my config file for the 'other' nodes in cluster.
So in my in 10.21.126.151 config file need to add this :
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.21.126.145:9200"]

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue sometime back. the fix is,

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts should point to the master nodes. From you question it is not clear which nodes are master, data , client etc.

Lets say,10.21.126.151 is your master node and remaining nodes are data nodes. try the following configuration in all the nodes

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.21.126.151","[::1]"]

node.master=true will set as master node
node.master=false and node.data=true will make a nodes as data node
node.client=true will make a node as client and a client code can neither be server not be data node
```

Comment: Added "[::1]" as the second option and my local nodes are connecting to a cluster. Try! this should work